# Select contact in All subscribe

Tags: journeybuilder, subscriber

I want to send SMS to contacts in all subscribe. What methods can I use to filter out contacts in all subscribe.
Because I implement SMS tracking through cloudpage, I need to propose contacts that are not in all subscribe from the sending list. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is there any way you can provide more information to clarify what you are asking for as I am confused. It sounds like you want to send an SMS to contacts in All Subscribers, but also want to make sure that they are not in All Subscribers before sending. Any clarity you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, maybe my problem is not clear enough. I'll describe it again. I want to send SMS to a group of people selected by me, but I want to make sure that all the people I want to send are in all subscribe. How can I eliminate the people who are not in all subscribe, leave the contacts in all subscribe and send SMS to these contacts?